# See user_id with django analytical and google analytics

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, django-templates, django-views

I'm using google analytics to track and profile my traffic on the site.
Under "User Explorer" section in GA, I can see the internal id and not my site's `user_id`.

How can I add my own `user_id` to google analytics?

I'm using `django-analytical` as well.

What I have to do in order to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en). What you should do is send the `user_id` in the following script:

```
ga('set', 'userId', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

So lets say in your index template:

```
<script>
    /*Google Analytics Script*/
    ga('set', 'userId', {% user_id %});
</script>
```